# Run exe (with answering promoted questions) in a batch mode

Tags: batch-file, exe

Could anyone help me with coding a batch file I want?

I have one exe file. Once I double click it, a black DOS window pops up and ask me "what name the text file has". I have to type in the full name with extension. After pressing enter, one more question followed up in the same black DOS window something like "how many columns in your file? 1. 10 columns; 2. 100 columns: 3. 150 columns. Thereafter, the exe file will ask a few more similar questions.

I want to let the exe process a number of input text files, only the names and data of input files are different, but actually the number of columns and the number of rows etc. are all the same.

So I thought maybe a batch file can run this exe (with answering promoted questions) in a batch mode.

The code in a bat file may look like:

```
@echo off
:: Let the exe run and process file1
start C:\Batexe\myprogram.exe
:: Could anyone help with the code to answer following up questions automatically (no need to even display the questions)?
:: Could anyone help with the code to answer following up questions automatically (no need to even display the questions)?
:: Could anyone help with the code to answer following up questions automatically (no need to even display the questions)?
:: Could anyone help with the code to answer following up questions automatically (no need to even display the questions)?

:: Let the exe run and process file2
:: Could anyone help with the code to answer following up questions automatically (no need to even display the questions)?
:: Could anyone help with the code to answer following up questions automatically (no need to even display the questions)?
:: Could anyone help with the code to answer following up questions automatically (no need to even display the questions)?
:: Could anyone help with the code to answer following up questions automatically (no need to even display the questions)?

:: Let the exe run and process file3
.
.
.
```

I have maybe 100 text input files. The above code blocks I may repeat 100 times (feel stupid). Hope I have made myself clear. So could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!!! I have posted the same questions elsewhere and not yet got an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your exe program gets its input from stdin, then you can pipe the responses to the program. There is no need to use START.

```
echo Response | yourProgram.exe
```

You can easily pipe a series of responses using parentheses

```
(
  echo Response 1
  echo Response 2
  echo Response 3
) | yourProgram.exe
```

You say that only the first response changes - the file name. You probably should use some form of FOR loop to iterate your file names. I'll give a few examples.

If you want to process all .TXT files in a particular directory:

```
@echo off
for %%F in ("pathToYourFolder\*.txt") do (
  echo %%F
  echo ConstantColumnCount
  echo ConstantRowCount
  echo etc.
) | yourProgram.exe
```

If you want to explicitly list the files in your batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (
  file1.txt
  optionalPath1\file2.txt
  file3.txt
  etc.
) do (
  echo %%F
  echo ConstantColumnCount
  echo ConstantRowCount
  echo etc.
) | yourProgram.exe
```

If you list all of the files to process in a file named FileList.txt, one file per line:

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (FileList.txt) do (
  echo %%F
  echo ConstantColumnCount
  echo ConstantRowCount
  echo etc.
) | yourProgram.exe
```

There are many more possibilities - the FOR command is quite flexible.